# Upgrade oracle jdbc drivers version 10.2 to 11.2.04

Tags: oracle11g

My java application is using oracle database 10.2 jdbc drivers so far with 11.2 database. I am planning to upgrade and saw that the text provided with the download link says "except NLS support".

```
Certified with JDK 8, JDK 7 and JDK 6: It contains the JDBC driver classes except classes for NLS support in Oracle Object and Collection types.
```

Do I have to add orai18n.jar to the class path, along with ojdbc6.jar?

When should I include that jar file? Is it when we store text in a different language in database?

Comment: Isn't what oracle says about that file enough information? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b10979/global.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yes, I would have to add the i18n jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Oracle you need to add that char if you use certain char sets

> Oracle's JDBC drivers provide Globalization Support (formerly NLS). Globalization Support allows you retrieve data or insert data into a database in any character set that Oracle supports. If the clients and the server use different character sets, then the driver provides the support to perform the conversions between the database character set and the client character set.

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b10979/global.htm for details